# CyberSource - Merchant Defined Data

Tags: php, mysql, date, time

CyberSource system require user Merchant Defined Data

Field Name is **MDD14** : **Time/date since last purchase**

```
<input type="hidden" id="merchant_defined_data14" name="merchant_defined_data14" value="<?php echo $time_difference;?>">
```

Problem 1;

If the customer is new, how can I calculate the time difference ? `(now()-max(date))`

For Example, 0 second is passed from last purchase.. Is it correct ?

Problem 2;

what is the date/time format of the CyberSource **MDD14** Time/date is required.

Time in Second ?
Date in ?

Sorry for these questions. They didnt provide me any document regarding this issue?

Is anyone coding CyberSource with PHP using MDD fields ?

Thanks for your help.

Regards..

Answer (score 1):

Merchant Defined Data is any custom data you want to send to CyberSource.  If you inherited this project, then the person/team before you set this up.  CyberSource doesn't require any Merchant Defined Data.  Merchant Defined Data is data defined by you as the merchant.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is mandatory to send Mdd fields because in documents it is clearly mentioned.

There is no need to send mdd14 date time field

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is mandatory to send Mdd fields because in documents it is clearly mentioned.

These fields are

'merchant_defined_data1'  => 'WC',  // Chanel of Operation

'merchant_defined_data2'  => 'YES', // 3D secure

'merchant_defined_data3' => 'category_name', // product category like category1, category2

'merchant_defined_data4' => 'product name', // product name.

'merchant_defined_data5'  =>  Yes/No // Previous Customer

'merchant_defined_data6'  =>  'Standard', // Shipping Method

'merchant_defined_data7'  => '1', // Number of Items Sold

'merchant_defined_data8'  =>  'USA', // Product Shipping Country

'merchant_defined_data20'  => 'NO', // VIP Customer

Not necessary to send mdd14 fields

If need any help further more please ask.

Answer (score 0):

Not mandatory or "required" by CYBERSOURCE, but it looks like they ARE necessary to @Ganesh-NeGi 's application in order to facilitate data sharing. Merchant Defined Data (MDD) fields are just a way to PASS data through the gateway and there are limitations in that you cannot send personal identifying information or health information data.